# Can't get props.location values in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting some props from a history.push from one page to another

**Component of the button I want to use**

```
const editToy = (properties) => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/toys/edit',
            data: properties
        })
    }

return (
        
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => (editToy(props))}>
             Edit toy
          </button>
        </div>
```

I checked with console.log in the new page and it show me all the values, but the problem is that when I want to get a single value of the toy, like the name, it show an error of undefined

**Component to edit Toy**

```
export default function EditToy(props) {

    //I bring the values of the toy I want to edit
    const { data } = props.location;
    console.log(data);
```

with the console.log(data) this is what I get

**Values of console log that show me in the webpage**

```
{value: {…}}
value:
createdAt: "2020-..."
description: "description"
imagenes: ["....jpg"]
price: price
title: "title"
updatedAt: "2020-..."
__v: 0
_id: "..."
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I tried with console.log(data.value.title) for example and it give an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `state` property in `push` method.

```
const editToy = (properties) => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/toys/edit',
            state: {
              data: properties
            }
        })
    }

return (
        
        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => (editToy(props))}>
             Edit toy
          </button>
        </div>
```

Component to edit Toy

```
const { state } = props.location;
console.log(state.data);
```

Comment: Yes! that was the problem. May I ask you what should I do to learn how to solve an error like this for myself for the next time? Or is a good think to ask here from StackOverflow when you feel stuck in some part of code?

Comment: I think it always best to study the docs first, which can solve your problem most of the time. If docs does not solve your problem, then you can ask the community.
FYI history docs: `https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history`